# Center columns content vertically with Bootstrap - table layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I converted Bootstrap columns into table cells in order to easily align its content vertically:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

html, body, .container, .row, [class*="col-"] {
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hm7p9vjw/2/

Everything works great in Chrome, however IE and FF won't keep the cells width equal to the col- values, it works as if the table-layout was set to auto (please try to open it with IE or FF to see what I mean).

Anything I am missing?

Comment: would you be interested in scrapping bootstrap and trying flexbox for this situation ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda, I was hoping to avoid flexbox, because this is the only part of the template I am working on where I need to align it vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the bootstrap css line 1134 and change max-width to width then the rendering in moz and chrome is the same and the image is nicely centered as in chrome.

the final code should look like this

```
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img, .carousel-inner > .item > img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a > img, .thumbnail > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh you were first. You are right, it's the .img-responsive class that is breaking the layout.

Comment: Please format your answer with code and I will choose your answer.

Comment: Super, except that I would not better modify the original Bootstrap files, but set it in my external stylesheets: .img-responsive { width: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the solution. Obviously, it's the `img` tag that's breaking the layout. `.img-reponsive` has it's `max-width` set to 100%, however it's `width` is not defined in CSS. If I set the width to 100% it works alright.

```
.img-responsive {
   width: 100%;
}
```